# Measuring Hits on a Webpage

Tags: web, click, html

I just had a brief question and hope someone can guide me in the right direction to helping me understand how that works and how its tracked. How do you measure the amount of times a link, button, or search is performed on a specific website? Do you run or can you run reports that give you this information?

Comment: How do you "measure" somebody has registered on your website? How do you "measure" somebody has placed an order?

Comment: Actually allow me to go more in depth... Our company has created a website for employees to go to when in doubt regarding (Time and Pay, Benefits, Policies... etc) So how would we know how many times each link or button was pressed or something was searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of that information ends up in your log files. If you have access to your web server log files, you can run them through any [log analyzer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=web+log+analyzer) to get your answers. This will capture all the data you requested *except* links to other websites.

If you want to capture offsite link clicks, or if you lack access to your log files, you'll need to embed javascript into your pages to record user activity. [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is one popular tool you can use.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular ways to get a detailed information is to use analytics tools, such as Google Analytics. You add a piece of Javascript code and you start gathering various information, which you can review in the site of the analytical tool.

Google Analytics is one of the most popular tools, although definitely not the only one. You can find other both free and commercial tools.